# AsyncTask is not functioning properly when called repetedly from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am making an app which sends update to web server when a songs starts playing...I do the the web server update through asynctask however some times some information gets skipped and some infos are sent repeatedly. In some case asyntask remain in running state making it not executing after that. Main thread works good.

I declared the instance like this in MainActivity

```
    private static AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mTask = null;
```

**code for Asynctask is**

```
private class SendingData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute(){
            //some task              
         }         
        protected void onPostExecute(Void params){
            Log.d("Tesing","After Post");
            super.onPostExecute(params);         
            }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            sendPost();
            return null;
        }

     }
```

**My call to asynctask when a new song changes in main thread. This is a repetitive call**

```
 if(mTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                   // My AsyncTask is done and onPostExecute was called
                   Log.d("AsyncTask Status","Finished");
                  mTask = new SendingData();
                  mTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);

              }else if(mTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){
                  Log.d("AsyncTask Status","Pending");
                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  mTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
              }
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared your `AsyncTask` as static variable. This means that your references will get mixed up, i.e. when you start a new `AsyncTask`, you will overwrite the previous reference with a new one.

Comment: Shall I make a new reference each time when encounter or have to call asynctask? how would i check the status of the previously called asynctask or do i just call a new one without thinking about the previous one like below
    new SendingData().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);

Comment: which is one is better AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR or AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR for repetitive task? Please explain me.